# Script to check that a file is readable and make a backup if it is

Tags: bash, scripts

I’m in a scripting class for Linux and am having a lot of trouble with this one. I do need help getting the answer but would be really appreciative if it can be explained so I can understand how to myself in the future.

> Write a script (called `read_file.sh`) that does these tasks:
>
> - Prompt users to enter a file name
> - Check if the file is readable
> - If the file is not readable, display message that the file cannon be read, and stop
> - If the file is readable, make a backup of the file and
> - Read each line of the file and display it

This is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Enter file name : "
read file
touch $file

# find out if file has read permission or not
[ -r $file ] && R="Read = yes" || R="Read = File cannot be read, and stop"

echo "$file permissions"
echo "$R"

[ -r "$file" ]; cp "$file" "$file.backup"     

if $R="Read = yes"
then echo "yes"

input="/student_data/student/read_file.sh"
while IFS= read line
do
echo "$line"
done < "$file"
```

Once I get past the read file permissions I cannot figure out how to write the rest of the script. I can't figure out how to write read each line of the file and display it. Some of this may have come about because I tried writing what I knew, then tried to fill in the rest with some cheat sheets my professor provided but I keep coming up with an error on line 26. i believe the rest is correct.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]. What is your question, i.e. where do you have problems and what’s unclear? Please add new information directly to your question ([edit]), *do not* use comments.

Comment: Please add new information directly to your question ([edit]), *do not* use comments. Which error messages are you getting? Please add them to your question as well.

Comment: You already know how to test whether it's readable (`[ -r "$file" ]`) - so now you just need to wrap all the other stuff in a conditional (`if [ -r "$file" ]; then <otherstuff> ; fi`

Comment: To make a backup you can simply _copy_ the file and give that copy another name, preferably indicating that it actually is a _backup_. E.g. `cp "$file" "$file.backup"`. Btw, I like this question because you clearly state it is homework and showed what you have already done. This is quite different from some folks just posting their assignment and -- if at all -- add the line "Please provide solution ASAP" (or sth. to that effect). :-)

Comment: Why do you `touch $file`? If the filename the user entered does not exist, you are creating it.

Comment: bash's `read` command can prompt: `read -p "Enter file name : " file`

Comment: Don't forget, you must quote the variable always: `touch "$file"` -- consider that the user enters a file name that contains a space.

Comment: Also, use `while IFS= read -r line` -- that gets you the exact contents of the line, even if there are any backslash-sequences

Comment: Thank you everyone, this was all helpful information I was still unable to get the script to read all the lines at the end but i'm sure that was something on my end.

Comment: Please update your question ([edit]) to reflect your current question.